# No custom service metrics in http://localhost/graph

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, grafana, prometheus-operator

Got it:

- running kubernetes cluster
- installed by bitnami/kube-prometheus
- added custom metrics for my services in kubernetes and they are visible in prometheus targets and service discovery

Problem:
I don't see any custom metrics for my services at http://localhost/graph and therefore I can not use any of the metrics to build graphs.

What is the search algorithm and solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: Can you share more details? Like the YAML of your statefulset/deployment, service? From where you're trying to access `localhost`? Are you using `port-forward` or not?

Comment: Yes, I can run Prometheus Dashboard via port-forward or simply clicking on the Lens appl. service "kube-prometheus".
I see all the metrics of my application, too, through port-forward or clicking in Lens in my Service.
Why metrics of my application are not available in http://localhost/graph (see scr.), despite the fact that they are in Target & Service Discovery? What are the reasons for this? Format, time, ...?